# Form Filter by Month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Problem with my filter for a form. The form contains activity of persons on specific dates during a month.

I have a combobox:
[image: combobox].

This combobox RowSource groups and formats dates into month name and year (mmmm jj):
[image: query]

The combobox is unbound and has this OnClick event:

```
    Private Sub Kombinationsfeld479_Click()
    Me.Filter = "[tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum] = " 
    & Format(Nz(Me!Kombinationsfeld479, Date), "\#yyyy-mm\#")
    Me.FilterOn = True
```

Filter of the form, when selecting October 18:

```
[tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsDatum] = #2018-10#
```

But in the End it just shows the 01.01.2018.
I know there is a format mistake somewhere.

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: Is there a possibility to add a  "Show All" selection within the combobox?

Comment: what data type is `TaetigkeitsDatum` dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: yes! its formatted as Date/Hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use combobox AfterUpdate event.

Format() function results in a text string, not a date. So the # delimiter does not apply, use apostrophe. Assuming data in field TaetigkeitsDatum is a true full date value, it must be formatted to match the combobox value. Don't execute the code if no value selected in combobox so Nz() should not be needed.

Yes, the combobox RowSource can have a "Show All" choice. This will require a UNION query.

```
SELECT "_Show All" AS Data FROM tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung
UNION SELECT Format(TaetigkeitsDatum, "mmmm yyyy") FROM tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung;
```

Then code can handle the selection.

```
If Me.Kombinationsfeld479 = "Show All" Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.Kombinationsfeld479) Then
    Me.Filter = "Format([TaetigkeitsDatum], 'mmmm yyyy') = '" & Me.Kombinationsfeld479 & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

Comment: WOW Thanks, that helped me a lot. But there is still a small mistake at `Me.Filter = "Format([TaetigkeitsDatum],"YYYY-MM") = '" & Me.Kombinationsfeld479 & "'"`  It says Syntax error and "expecting end of statement" at `"YYYY-MM"`      tried some rework, but nothing helped. @June7

Comment: Sorry, edited answer. Replaced embedded quotes with apostrophes in the Format() expression.

Comment: Is it possible, when opening the form, to show the datas of the current month? Things like: _standard value_ at the _Kombinationsfeld479_  - `Format(Datum();'mm')` does not work, bc its not loading, hes just putting the Number in f.e.    The User experience is just bad, when the Users is switching between the tabs and always has to set the filter again. The filter even resets at my Navigationform. @June7

Comment: Isn't combobox on the form you are filtering? Try DefaultValue of `Format(Datum(); "MMMM YYYY")`. I NEVER use Navigation form. Perhaps should start a new question.